Correctly translate text with Markdown using deepl-node
I am trying to translate XML documents using my NodeJS/Loopback 3 server, as well as the deepl-node library.
My code so far looks like so:
const { Translator, TextResult } = require('deepl-node');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

const apiKey = process.env.DEEPL_API_KEY;
const translator = apiKey ? new Translator(apiKey) : null;

const DeepLService = {
  // Function to escape markdown-sensitive characters
  escapeMarkdown: (text) => {
    return text
      .replace(/\*/g, '__ASTERISK__')  // Escape asterisks used for bold and italics
      .replace(/~/g, '__TILDE__')      // Escape tilde used for strikethrough
      .replace(/\n/g, '__NEWLINE__');   // Escape newlines to preserve them
  },

  // Function to restore escaped markdown characters
  unescapeMarkdown: (text) => {
    return text
      .replace(/__ASTERISK__/g, '*')
      .replace(/__TILDE__/g, '~')
      .replace(/__NEWLINE__/g, '\n');
  },

  // Function to translate attributes like 'title' inside <media> tags
  translateAttributes: async (parsedXml, targetLang) => {
    const mediaTitles = [];

    // Extract all media titles that need to be translated
    if (parsedXml.workflow && parsedXml.workflow.worktask) {
      parsedXml.workflow.worktask.forEach((task) => {
        if (task.workitem) {
          task.workitem.forEach((workitem) => {
            if (workitem.media) {
              workitem.media.forEach((media) => {
                if (media.$ && media.$.title) {
                  // Escape markdown in the title
                  mediaTitles.push(DeepLService.escapeMarkdown(media.$.title));
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }

    // Translate media titles
    const translatedTitles = await Promise.all(
      mediaTitles.map(async (title) => {
        const result = await translator.translateText(title, null, targetLang);
        return DeepLService.unescapeMarkdown(result.text); // Unescape after translation
      })
    );

    // Restore translated titles into the media elements
    let titleIndex = 0;
    if (parsedXml.workflow && parsedXml.workflow.worktask) {
      parsedXml.workflow.worktask.forEach((task) => {
        if (task.workitem) {
          task.workitem.forEach((workitem) => {
            if (workitem.media) {
              workitem.media.forEach((media) => {
                if (media.$ && media.$.title) {
                  media.$.title = translatedTitles[titleIndex++];
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }

    return parsedXml;
  },

  parseXML: async (xml, targetLang) => {
    try {
      const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
      const builder = new xml2js.Builder();
      const parsedXml = await parser.parseStringPromise(xml);

      // Preprocessing: Escape markdown-sensitive characters in <text> tags
      if (parsedXml.workflow && parsedXml.workflow.worktask) {
        parsedXml.workflow.worktask.forEach((task) => {
          if (task.workitem) {
            task.workitem.forEach((workitem) => {
              if (workitem.text) {
                workitem.text[0] = DeepLService.escapeMarkdown(workitem.text[0]);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }

      // Translate media 'title' attributes separately
      const updatedXmlWithAttributes = await DeepLService.translateAttributes(parsedXml, targetLang);

      return builder.buildObject(updatedXmlWithAttributes);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(`Parsing error: ${err}`);
    }
  },

  translate: async (xml, targetLang) => {
    try {
      if (!translator) {
        return xml;
      }

      const updatedXml = await DeepLService.parseXML(xml, targetLang);

      const result = await translator.translateText(
        updatedXml,
        null,
        targetLang,
        {
          tagHandling: 'xml',
          splitSentences: 'nonewlines',
          ignoreTags: ['fe', 'type', 'symbol', 'media', 'trainingtype', 'WorldMap', 'worldmap', 'assetbundle', 'creationTime']
        }
      );

      // Postprocessing: Unescape markdown characters after translation
      let translatedXml = result.text;
      if (translatedXml) {
        translatedXml = DeepLService.unescapeMarkdown(translatedXml);
      }

      return {
        translatedXML: translatedXml,
        sourceLang: result.detectedSourceLang
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('DeepL API error:', error.message);
      throw new Error('Translation failed');
    }
  },

  getSupportedTargetLanguages: () => {
    if (!translator) {
      return [];
    }
    return translator.getTargetLanguages();
  }
};

module.exports = DeepLService;

As you can see, I am trying to translate everything inside the <text> and <title> tags, sometimes those tags can contain markdown (especially the <text> tags).
The problem that I am having here is that some languages seem to miscreate the markdown when translated. For example, if on the original document I have this: **bold text**, on the French translation it looks like this: ***bold text__** (ignore the lack of translation, I am focusing on the markdown for now).
It also sometimes takes the first asterisk away on unordered list markdown:
Original: * One * Two * Three
Translated: One * Two * Three
These errors don't happen across all languages, it's very inconsistent.
So, my question is, what would be the best way to approach the markdown translation in DeepL so it's consistent across all languages?

huh, you're saying the deepl service returns something wrong? there isn't much you can do about that, can you?

If I see it right, you are sending __ASTERISK__ instead of * in your text, etc - this would confuse the model and lead to worse translation. DeepL does not natively support Markdown, but by just leaving the markdown in the text I would expect higher quality than with the escaped text.
Additionally, DeepL supports XML - you can try using ignore tags to escape the markdown without translating it.
